# How to connect excel to sharepoint and allowing multiple users to use the excel file

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

Alright, here's a difficult one for all the excel champions out there!

I'm making a time registration system for a small company. It contains one excel file with a list of all the different work tasks in the company. Now every employee has their own excel file, where they are to register the hours they spend on the individual tasks. The challenge is now to get the employee files to load the work tasks from the work task list document. Sounds easy!

The challenge is that all files are placed on a sharepoint drive. I've succesfully connected the registrations files with the work tasks file through my own sharepoint login, and everything works fine on my computer. Now when another employee opens their excel file for registration on their own computer, they are prompted to connect to sharepoint, however this somehow never succedes. The connection needs to be between two sharepoint files, which everybody can access, and not be dependent on any specific user logins.

Any ideas of how to make this connection in the right way?

What I'm doing right now is; Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From Sharepoint -> nameofcompany.sharepoint/site/nameofsite
And then from here I do the data transform needed.

I really don't want to make one huge excel file containing all the information, but dealing with sharepoint is driving me nuts...

Hope anybody can help!

Comment: Do you want many users to access the same excel file? If yes, you just need to copy the URL of the file in your SharePoint site and send it to another user, then the user could use his certificate to access the file.

Comment: I want many users to access individual files, I create, which all gets information from a sheet in another excel file I also create.